# Ubuntu 20.04 not recognizing keyboard

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

After updating to version 20.04, the keyboard doesn't work anymore. I read in some other answers to use an external keyboard, but this is exactly what I am doing. I tried to boot with a old kernel, but I couldn't because when booting I hold the SHIFT button but it is not recognized.

**Computer Info** (obtained with *sudo lshw | grep product >file*)

```
product: System Product Name (SKU)
   product: B150I PRO GAMING/AURA
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
         product: KHX2133C14/16G
         product: KHX2133C14/16G
      product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
         product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
            product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
            product: GP102 HDMI Audio Controller
         product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
            product: xHCI Host Controller
               product: AX68002
                  product: USB Optical Mouse
                  product: Asus Keyboard
            product: xHCI Host Controller
         product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
         product: Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
         product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5
         product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9
         product: B150 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
         product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
         product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
         product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
         product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
         product: Samsung SSD 850
   product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

**Output of lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:1125 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b95:6802 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX68002
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: In order to answer this question with any sort of accuracy, it will be helpful to know the brand and model of your computer. If this is a desktop machine, knowing the model number of the keyboard could also be useful. With specific questions come specific answers 

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just added the info required. Is it eneough? Let me know if you need more @matigo

Comment: AX68002 corresponds to KVM 2 ports USB. https://www.plantautomation-technology.com/products/asix-electronics-corporation/2-port-usb-kvm-switch-soc-ax68002 What is the output of executing **lsusb** ?

Comment: @CarlesMateo added it in the question

Comment: @Deffo Thanks. In my system I see perfectly clear the Keyboard: ```Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120``` Can you try connecting another keyboard?. Some times drivers fail. Something to try too, is to plug the keyboard to another port.

Comment: @CarlesMateo already tried changing keyboard and changing...none of these worked

Comment: Any messages if you do ```dmesg -T | grep -i "keyboard"``` ?

Comment: @CarlesMateo never mind, I just re-installed Ubuntu and now it works

Comment: Thanks for the update @Deffo.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but ran into the same problem, used Tasksel to remove a package [BIG NO NO NOO!] and it removed lots of other packages and caused all USB ports to stop working.
I sadly had to reinstall cause the system was very damaged.
If you can look at what packages you have removed or the installation process removed and see if anything looks suspicious.